# How to install iOS application from src, .app, or .ipa via command line to hardware device

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcodebuild

**For test automation (GUI test, not XCUnitTest) purposes, I need to install an iOS app onto a physical hardware device.**

I'm looking for:

- a replacement to [Fruitstrap](https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap) (it has been abandoned)
- or a way to perform XCode's "Build & Run" action on a target device

I've tried:

1. using `xcodebuild` and pointing the `-destination` argument at the target device and providing build actions of `clean` and `install`
2. It finds the target device and begins cleaning and then installing.
3. At the end of all the files being compiled and the app being signed, I get a success message

> ```
> ** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
> ```

But, alas, no app is installed on my phone.

This is my full xcodebuild command:

```
xcodebuild 
    -destination platform=iOS,id=######## \
    clean install
```

[**Here's the gist of the output**](https://gist.github.com/JessicaSachs/c3b8e71d30305757de83)

Creative suggestions welcome.

I'm considering writing an applescript if needed, but wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fruitstrap is, for the time being, working and installing the app correctly.

```
/path/to/fruitstrap \
install -id ##udid### \
--bundle "/Users/#######/path/to/application.ipa"
```

Other, more maintained solutions are still welcome.

Limitations:

- Need to have a prebuilt .ipa file
- Target device must be signed with a provisioning profile that includes the target device's udid

Comment: i need your inputs on this - am doing automation testing for my ios app using appium how do i install my app on iOS simulator using appium. If you can help me plz..

Comment: Hey unfortunately I haven't worked with Appium in years. Try following the tutorial on appiums website.